# "IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed" in fragment transaction

Tags: android, fragment

I have activity named MainActivity which is used a method selectItem() for fragment transaction.Two fragments of this activity named LocationSendActivity and MapActivty. When MainActivity selected LocationSendActivity then LocationSendActivity  calls service named SendMapData.SendMapData  calls MapActivity using method named selectItem() of MainActivity using it's object, after this it shows illegalStateException error.

MainActivity...

```
package com.example.map;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.OnNavigationListener;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    public int n;
    private String lat,lng;
    private String[] mPlanetTitles;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    private CharSequence bartitle;
    // private Handler handler;
    // private boolean maprefreash;
    public static double lat10=0,lng10=0;
    FragmentManager fm;

    Fragment map = new MapActivity();
    Fragment msg = new MessageActivity();
    Fragment send = new LocationSendActivity();
    Fragment find = new LocationFindActivity();
    Fragment set = new SettingActivty();
    Fragment dia = new AlertDialogFragment();

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.drawer_main);

        //get data from url
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        // check if this intent is started via custom scheme link
        if (Intent.ACTION_VIEW.equals(intent.getAction())) {

          Uri uri = intent.getData();
          // may be some test here with your custom uri
          lat = uri.getQueryParameter("lat1"); 
          lng = uri.getQueryParameter("lng1"); 
          //lat10=Double.parseDouble(lat);
          Log.e("LatMain",lat);
          Log.e("LngMain",lng);
          try{
             lat10=Double.parseDouble(lat);
             lng10=Double.parseDouble(lng);
             }catch(Exception e){
                  e.printStackTrace();
              } 
        }

        //Action bar 
        ActionBar ab=getSupportActionBar();
        ab.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_blue_light)));
        bartitle= ab.getTitle();

        mPlanetTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.item);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

        //set the adapter for list view
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.drawer_item,R.id.textView1, mPlanetTitles));

        //set the list's click listener
        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

        // set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer opens
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);
        mDrawerLayout.setScrimColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

        mDrawerToggle =new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,mDrawerLayout,R.drawable.ic_drawer,R.string.drawer_open,
                R.string.drawer_close){
                   /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state. */

                    public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(bartitle);
                        supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
                    }           
                   /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */

                    public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Open Drawer");
                        supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
                    }
                };
             // Set the drawer toggle as the DrawerListener
                mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
                getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
                getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            selectItem(0);
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Map");
            }


      //set dropdown menu navigation in action bar
            ab.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);
            String[] data=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.dropDown);
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getBaseContext(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,data);
            ActionBar.OnNavigationListener navigation=new OnNavigationListener() {

                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int position, long id) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    return false;
                }
            };
            /** Setting dropdown items and item navigation listener for the actionbar */
            ab.setListNavigationCallbacks(adapter, navigation);

    }

    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
          return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    } 

    private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            selectItem(position);
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            setTitle(mPlanetTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);

        }
    }
    public void selectItem(int position) {
        n=position;
        if(n==5){
            lat10=0;lng10=0;
            this.finish();
        }
        fm=getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        // FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        // Locate Position
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, map);
            ft.addToBackStack(null);
            break;
        case 1:
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, msg);
            ft.addToBackStack(null);
            break;
        case 2:
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, send);
            ft.addToBackStack(null);
            break;
        case 3:
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, find);
            ft.addToBackStack(null);
            break;
        case 4:
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, set);
            ft.addToBackStack(null);
            break; 
        }
    //  ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.commit();

    }

    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        bartitle = title;
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(bartitle);
    } 
    public void onBackPressed(){
        super.onBackPressed();
        if(n==0){
            lat10=0;lng10=0;
            this.finish();
        }
        else{
        super.onBackPressed();
        selectItem(0);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Map");
        }  
    }



}
```

LocationSendActivity........

```
package com.example.map;

import java.util.Calendar;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import updatedata.TimeInterval;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class LocationSendActivity extends Fragment {
    private double latt,lngt;
    private TextView tv1,tv2;
    private Button btn;
    public static CheckBox cb;
    private Handler handler;
    EditText id,email;
    String mob1,lat1,lng1,email1,time;
    long total,min;
    double val;
    // int test;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        latt=MapActivity.latitude;
        lngt=MapActivity.longitude;   
        View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.locationsend, container, false);
        tv1=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        tv2=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView4); 
        id=(EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        email=(EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        btn=(Button)v.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        cb=(CheckBox)v.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        handler=new Handler();

        //get time from time interval
        min=TimeInterval.time;
        if(min == 1){
         val=0.5*60;    
        }else if(min == 2){
         val=1*60;  
        }else if(min == 3){
         val=3*60;  
        }else if(min == 4){
         val=5*60;  
        }else if(min == 5){
         val=15*60; 
        }
        else{
             val=0.5*60;    
            }
        total=(long) (val*1000);
        Log.e("Seconds", String.valueOf(total));;

        tv1.setText(String.valueOf(latt));
        tv2.setText(String.valueOf(lngt));
        lat1=String.valueOf(latt);
        lng1=String.valueOf(lngt);

        //Button for send data
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setData();
                time= java.text.DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
                Log.e("mob,lat,lng", mob1+" "+lat1+" "+lng1);

                new SendData(mob1,lat1,lng1,email1,time).execute();
            }
        });

        //checkbox for send data in interval
        cb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 if(cb.isChecked()){
                    MapActivity map=new MapActivity(); 
                    FragmentManager fm=getFragmentManager();
                    FragmentTransaction ft1 = fm.beginTransaction();
                    ft1.replace(R.id.content_frame, map);
                    ft1.addToBackStack(null);
                    ft1.commit();   
                    getActivity().startService(new Intent(getActivity(),SendMapData.class)); 
                    // handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000); 
                }else{
                    getActivity().stopService(new Intent(getActivity(),SendMapData.class));
                   // handler.removeCallbacks(runnable,null);

                }
            }
        });

        return v;
    }

    /* Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
           @Override
           public void run() {
              // do what you need to do
               // new sendMapData(mob1,lat1,lng1,email1,time);
               new SendData(mob1,lat1,lng1,email1,time).execute();
              // and here comes the "trick" 
               handler.postDelayed(this, total);
           }
        }; */

    protected void setData() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        mob1=id.getText().toString();
        // mob.setText("");
        email1=email.getText().toString();
        // email.setText("");
    }

    class SendData extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{
        String mob2,email2,lat2,lng2,time2,suc;
        int success,val;

        public SendData(String mob, String lat,String lng, String email,String time) {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            this.mob2=mob;
            this.email2=email;
            this.time2=time;
            this.lat2=lat;
            this.lng2=lng;
        }

        protected void onPreExecute(){
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            FunctionCall fc=new FunctionCall();
            JSONObject jo=fc.sendData(mob2, lat2, lng2, email2, time2 );
            try{
                 success=jo.getInt("success");
                 // val=success.to
                 // Log.e("success", succ);

            }catch(JSONException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url){

             getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if (success==1){
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Data Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Data Not Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } 

                } 
            }); 

        }
    }
}
```

SendMapData....

```
    package com.example.map;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SendMapData extends Service {
    private Handler handler;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        // We want this service to continue running until it is explicitly
        // stopped, so return sticky.
        handler=new Handler();
        MainActivity ma=new MainActivity();
        ma.selectItem(0);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Hold Map To Send Updated Data", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 10000);   
        //doSomethingRepeatedly();
        return START_STICKY;
        }

    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
           @Override
           public void run() {
              // do what you need to do
              // new sendMapData(mob1,lat1,lng1,email1,time);
              // new SendData(mob1,lat1,lng1,email1,time).execute();
              // and here comes the "trick" 
               Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Send Updated Data", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               handler.postDelayed(this, 10000);
           }
        };

    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        handler.removeCallbacks(runnable,null);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Destroyed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

logcat

```
01-10 16:19:44.391: E/AndroidRuntime(15320): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.example.map.SendMapData@32657128 with Intent { cmp=com.example.map/.SendMapData }: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed
01-10 16:19:44.391: E/AndroidRuntime(15320):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3071)
01-10 16:19:44.391: E/AndroidRuntime(15320):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$3600(ActivityThread.java:127)
01-10 16:19:44.391: E/AndroidRuntime(15320):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2098)
01-10 16:19:44.391: E/AndroidRuntime(15320):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-10 16:19:44.391: E/AndroidRuntime(15320):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-10 16:19:44.391: E/AndroidRuntime(15320):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4635)
01-10 16:19:44.391: E/AndroidRuntime(15320):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-10 16:19:44.391: E/AndroidRuntime(15320):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-10 16:19:44.391: E/AndroidRuntime(15320):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:916)
01-10 16:19:44.391: E/AndroidRuntime(15320):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:674)
01-10 16:19:44.391: E/AndroidRuntime(15320):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-10 16:19:44.391: E/AndroidRuntime(15320): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed
01-10 16:19:44.391: E/AndroidRuntime(15320):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1358)
01-10 16:19:44.391: E/AndroidRuntime(15320):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:595)
01-10 16:19:44.391: E/AndroidRuntime(15320):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:574)
01-10 16:19:44.391: E/AndroidRuntime(15320):    at com.example.map.MainActivity.selectItem(MainActivity.java:198)
01-10 16:19:44.391: E/AndroidRuntime(15320):    at com.example.map.SendMapData.onStartCommand(SendMapData.java:23)
01-10 16:19:44.391: E/AndroidRuntime(15320):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3061)
```

Comment: Where did you start this service on MainActivity? You should firstly start this SendMapData as a service on your activity.

Comment: Service started from SendMapData fragment........